# Prove by induction that ${x}^{2k}-{y}^{2k}=(x+y)t$ for all natural numbers $k$ and $t$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Although it is an elementary algebraic result proved easily using algebra but I wanted to prove it inductively.

In my endeavor to do this, I've reached to the step which not only requires the preceding term but also the penultimate term to be true but in induction we only starts with the assumption of the previous term to be true. So, I'm left wondering how could I proceed further?

My proof goes like this:

$a(k)={x}^{2k}-{y}^{2k}$

$a(1)={x}^{2}-{y}^{2}=(x+y)(x-y)$

So, $a(1)$ is true.

Now, let us assume that $a(n)$ is true.

So, ${x}^{2n}-{y}^{2n}=(x+y)p$    for some polynomial $p$

Now,

$a(n+1)={x}^{2n+2}-{y}^{2n+2}$

$={x}^{2n+2}-{y}^{2n+2}-{x}^{2}{y}^{2n}+{x}^{2}{y}^{2n}+{y}^{2}{x}^{2n}-{y}^{2}{x}^{2n}$

$={x}^{2}({x}^{2n}-{y}^{2n})+{y}^{2}({x}^{2n}-{y}^{2n})-{x}^{2}{y}^{2}({x}^{2n-2}-{y}^{2n-2})$

$=({x}^{2}+{y}^{2})({x}^{2n}-{y}^{2n})-{x}^{2}{y}^{2}({x}^{2n-2}-{y}^{2n-2})$

$=({x}^{2}+{y}^{2})((x+y)p)-{x}^{2}{y}^{2}({x}^{2n-2}-{y}^{2n-2})$

Now I'm stuck with ${x}^{2}{y}^{2}({x}^{2n-2}-{y}^{2n-2})$ divisibility by 11 that is the divisibility of $a(n-1)$ term by 11.

Comment: Are you assuming that $t$ depends on $k$?  That seems like it'd be necessary, but I don't see that above.

Comment: @Mark No. I'm expressing $t$ only as a quotient here.

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to prove.  Is it that given $k$ and $t$ you can find $x$ and $y$ to make the equation true?  If you show your proof so far, we will find helping much easier.

Comment: What * are* you trying to prove.  a_k = x^2k - y^2k isn't a statement at all. So it can't be true or false. Your statement in the title is obviously not true.  (x + y)t = xt + yt  ne x^2k - y^2k for *any* k,t and certainly not * every* possible k, t.  (It's not true if t =3 and k =6,543,896).  And (x+y)(x-y) does not equal (x+y)t for any t. So a_1 isn't true.  I think you have some other meaning in mind, but how you have stated it isn't at all clear.

Comment: Check if $a(2)$ is true. Then make one more assumption : $a(n-1)$ is true. We have $x^{2n-2} - y^{2n-2} = (x+y)p'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C(k)$ be the claim that there exists a polynomial $P_k(x,y)$ in $x$, $y$ such that $$x^{2k} - y^{2k} = (x+y)P_k(x,y).$$  Then a proof by induction might be as follows.  For $k = 0$, we have $$x^0 - y^0 = 0 = (x+y) P_0(x,y)$$ the trivial choice $P_0(x,y) = 0$.  For $k = 1$, we have $$x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y),$$ thus $P_1(x,y) = x-y$ establishes $C(1)$ as true.  So there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $C(k)$ is true for all $0 \le k \le m$.  Then consider $$x^{2(m+1)} - y^{2(m+1)} = (x^{2m} - y^{2m})(x^2 + y^2) - x^2 y^2 (x^{2(m-1)} - y^{2(m-1)}).$$  But since $k = m-1$ and $k = m$ both satisfy $0 \le k \le m$, we have $$x^{2m} - y^{2m} = (x+y)P_m(x,y) \\ x^{2(m-1)} - y^{2(m-1)} = (x+y)P_{m-1}(x,y),$$ hence $$x^{2(m+1)} - y^{2(m+1)} = (x+y)\left((x^2+y^2)P_m(x,y) - x^2 y^2 P_{m-1}(x,y)\right) = (x+y)P_{m+1}(x,y),$$ with the choice $$P_{m+1}(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)P_m(x,y) - x^2 y^2 P_{m-1}(x,y).$$  This establishes the induction step, hence claim $C(m+1)$ is also true.  Moreover, this proof gives us a recursion relationship for the polynomial $P_k(x,y)$, with the initial conditions $P_0(x,y) = 0$, $P_1(x,y) = x-y$.  We could use this to calculate $$P_2(x,y) = x^3 - x^2 y + x y^2 - y^3, \\ P_3(x,y) = x^5 - x^4 y + x^3 y^2 - x^2 y + x y^4 - y^5, \\ \text{etc.}$$  Of course, this suggests the *explicit* solution $$P_k(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^{2k-1} x^{2k-1-j} (-y)^j,$$ and we could perform the multiplication $$\begin{align*} (x+y)P_k(x,y) &= (x+y)\sum_{j=0}^{2k-1} x^{2k-1-j} (-y)^j \\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{2k-1} x^{2k-j} (-y)^j - \sum_{j=0}^{2k-1} x^{2k-1-j} (-y)^{j+1} \\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{2k-1} x^{2k-j} (-y)^j - \sum_{j=1}^{2k} x^{2k-j} (-y)^j \\ &= x^{2k} (-y)^0 - x^{2k-2k} (-y)^{2k} \\ &= x^{2k} - ((-1)^2)^k y^{2k} \\ &= x^{2k} - y^{2k}. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Fair enough, but it's a bit of a stretch to claim $P_k (x,y) = t \in \mathbb N $ as the title and body claim.  Could it mean that the op is trying to prove for all natural k,t there exist real x, y so that $x^{2k}-y^{2k}= (x+y)t $ as Ross millikan suggested it might be?  (Although all things considered, I think you are probably right in your interpretation.)